# using a void method with two int parameters instead of an int?

Tags: java, methods, parameters, error-handling, void

I have no problem using a method int to run this program; however I wanted to be able to learn how to do the `void` method.

I know the `return` statement isn't necessary in `void`, and for `void` with two `int` parameters. In my book it said parameters should be written as `(int a, int b)`.

However, in my code for lines 16 and 17

```
sum = computeSum(num1, num2);
product = computeProduct(num1, num2);)
```

I get the error `incompatible types, void cannot be converted to int`.

How do I rectify this for future reference? Thanks so much!

```
 import java.util.Scanner;

 public class Lab6
 {
     public static void main (String [] args)
     {      
         //create a scanner object for receiving user input
         Scanner keyboard = new Scanner (System.in);
         int num1, num2, sum, product;

         System.out.println ("Please enter an integer: ");
         num1 = keyboard.nextInt();
         System.out.println ("Please enter another integer: ");
         num2 = keyboard.nextInt(); 

         sum = computeSum(num1, num2);
         product = computeProduct(num1, num2);
     }

     public static void computeSum(int num1, int num2)
     {
         int sum = 0;
         sum = num1 + num2; 

         System.out.println ("The sum of your integers is " + sum);
     }

     public static void computeProduct(int num1, int num2)
     {
         int product = 0; 
         product = num1 * num2;

         System.out.println("\nThe product of your integers is: " + product);
     }
 }
```

Comment: void means method does not return a value, so how will u get the product? The only way is that you set a variable which is visible in both calling method and called method.

Answer (score 2):

The method `computeSum()`'s return type is `void`, i.e. it returns nothing which means it cannot be assigned to a variable. Hence, the following is not possible:

```
sum = computeSum(num1, num2);
```

Answer (score 1):

As you said, `void` methods don't return a value, so `sum = computeSum(num1, num2);` makes no sense, as `computeSum` doesn't return anything.

You should try using...

```
computeSum(num1, num2);
computeProduct(num1, num2);
```

instead...

Comment: Thank you! I figured it out, I copied the program over and forgot to take that out. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

[Steve Bourne](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stephen_R._Bourne) proposed that Algol68's VOID be defined as `MODE VOID = STRUCT()`.  When Steve arrived at [Bell Labs](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bell_Labs) he talked Dennis into adding void as a type in C. It saved the instruction loading register for return value. Also when Steve got to the lab C types were like PL/1 namely offsets from any base you liked. They changed to A68 types but be the specific reason for this change is now lost. A few other A68isms ended up in C.
Speculation: Std C could have considered `typedef struct{}void` ...